# Customize UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, customization, uisearchdisplaycontroller

[alt text http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/5992/searchdisplaycontroller.png](http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/5992/searchdisplaycontroller.png)

Are the following objects customizable?

**1. UISearchBar Scope Buttons (UISegmentedController)**

**2. UIResultsTableView**

**3. Keyboard (at least so it's colored black)**

Comment: What are you using to generate it: A nib or code?

Comment: I am using code. I was able to customize everything so thanks everyone for their help, however I wasn't able to delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

[alt text http://img527.imageshack.us/img527/9775/searchdisplaycontrollerz.png](http://img527.imageshack.us/img527/9775/searchdisplaycontrollerz.png)

I was able to change the segmented control by a sort-of hack code:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {
        if ([subview2 isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
            UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)subview2;
            segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        }           
    }
}}
```

However the buttons are HUGE, how could I fix it so they are just as pretty as the original?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to customize the tableview by using the following code:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(19.0 / 255.0) green:(19.0 / 255.0) blue:(19.0 / 255.0) alpha:1.0];
tableView.separatorColor  = [UIColor blackColor]; }
```

However when you touch the cancel button, the interface will flash white before going back to the original tableview. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was also never able to get the buttons to be smaller despite trying every segmentedControlStyle.  Here's the code I needed to use to at least get the tint color correct on IOS4:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    static BOOL tintAlreadyChanged = NO;
    if (tintAlreadyChanged) return;

    NSLog(@"Searching subViews for UISegmentControl:");
    //fix segmented control
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        //NSLog(@"\n\nsubView = %@",subview);
        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {
            //NSLog(@"subView2 = %@",subview2);
            for (UIView *subview3 in subview2.subviews) {
                //NSLog(@"subView3 = %@",subview3);
                if ([subview3 isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
                    NSLog(@"Found UISegment SubView = %@",subview3);
                    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)subview3;
                    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
                    tintAlreadyChanged = YES;
                }
            }                       
        }
    }
}
```