# Upon exiting UISearchDisplayController's search table view, the screen flashes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using UISearchDisplayController to implement the search feature on a table view.  My table view cell uses custom background image.

When you first type a letter into the search textfield, the search results start appearing.  However, when I click cancel at this point, the screen flashes white.  This is not as noticeable if everything uses the standard white, but since my table view cell uses custom background, the white flashing is quite noticeable.

Where is this flashing coming from? Is there anything I can do to remove this flashing? (You can see this flashing on standard Apple apps too but it may not be very obvious if the table view uses white background)

Another SO post mentioned this very problem too - [Customize UISearchDisplayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559676/customize-uisearchdisplaycontroller) (search for the word "Flash")

Answer (score 0):

Found a good work around for this [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/94190) at Apple's Dev Forums.

Basically, the flash is by design and there isn't any way to customize/disable it. However, the poster in the link came up with a simple work around -- remove the search display table view all together (removeFromSuperView). Works absolutely fine for me.